# Undefined reference in Kdevelop

Tags: reference, ubuntu-12.04, undefined-reference, kdevelop, printf-debugging

I have main.cpp, linking test function from io.c

```
#include <iostream>
#include "io.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

io.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "io.h"

void test() {
printf("hee");
}
```

and I configure CMakeLists.txt as following:

```
project(test)
set(MyProjectSources io.c io.h main.cpp )
add_executable(test ${MyProjectSources})
```

However, when I build a project, the error of undefined reference appears.
Please help me.

PS: If main.cpp references to 2 libraries such as l1.h and l2.h. How to link these to main.cpp?

Comment: without posting the actual error there is nothing we can help you with. also: you probably don't want to add io.h (a header file!) to the list of sources.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the error. Nevertheless, it looks like you are missing to link against some libraries.

Also note this is a CMake issue, not a KDevelop's. You'll probably find more literature if you research cmake.